# How to calculate the average direction of a cluster of unit vectors?

Tags: math, vector

Having a set of high-dimensional unit vectors, how to calculate out an unit vector, which indicates the average direction on these vectors?

Would averaging these vectors work? but the result won't be an unit vector.

Comment: What's a unit vector? It's a vector of length 1. If `v` is a vector, and `||v||` is its length, then `(1/||v||) v` is a unit vector with same direction as `v`.

Comment: @Stef But I'm not sure if the direction of averaged vector is the same concept as average direction of these vectors.

Comment: Quite frankly, "the average direction" is underspecified and might mean several different things. "the direction of the average vector", on the other hand, is a simple concept.

Comment: There may not be a sensible 'average direction'. In 2D what is the average of north and south? It seems like the average of the unit vectors is a reasonable way to go, but if that average is very small -- averaging almost north and almost south -- it may be just noise. You might want to take the length of the average into account when deciding if there is a sensible average direction.